# Batch Utility to Move Files (Partial File Name Match) to Folders (Partial Folder Name Match)

Tags: batch-file

I've searched and have been unable to find a solution for this.  This solution needs to work on a Windows machine.

I've created a group of folders based off a text file that have the pertinent information needed for the folder.

All folders are named in this manner:

```
X1234501__ASFX___FSU-xx-xxx
```

I have a series of word documents that are named in this manner:

```
X1234501 ASFX 2_10_2014.docx
```

What I need is a batch utility that will move the word documents to the corresponding folder where the first 8 characters are the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the word documents stored in the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work if all Word documents are in a single directory (`DOC_PATH`), and all the directories they are being moved to are also in a single directory (`DIR_PATH`)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P DOC_PATH="Enter full file path to Word documents."
SET /P DIR_PATH="Enter full file path to directories."

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a IN (
    'DIR /B %DOC_PATH%\*.docx'
) DO (
    FOR /D %%i IN (%DIR_PATH%\%%a*) DO (
        MOVE "%DOC_PATH%\%%a %%b" "%DIR_PATH%\%%i"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the folders set up:

```
:start
   @echo off
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
   for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir *.docx /b') do (
      set filename=%%f
      set folder8=!filename:~0,8!
      set "targetfolder="
      for /f %%l in ('dir "!folder8!"*.* /a:d /b') do (
         set targetfolder=%%l
      )
   if defined targetfolder move "!filename!" "!targetfolder!"   
   )   
:end
```